# jQuery .html() large load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, load

I have been testing the jQuery .html() function and I have found that it does not work with large amounts of text, see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/AHBBz/). However the code for that is bug free, and a much simplified [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/R2JbX/) works perfectly.

I know that this probably isn't the best way to include large amounts of data into a div, but I intend to eventually load the data in from various arrays, and the code was meant to be a sort of constructor.

So onto my question: what am I doing wrong? Can jQuery just not handle that amount of text? And if so what is the best way to load multiple instances of the same html, with different text/urls in some parts, using jQuery/JavaScript/JSON? Should I populate the data from an array?

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT based on answers**

Hi thank, stupidly I overlooked an undefined variable. Here is a new [working test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/AHBBz/1/). What I am trying to accomplish is to have multiple blog posts that follow the same structural formula loaded into a page by jQuery 6 at a time. Is the best way to store this data in an array? And then populate the contents of those elements from the array?

Comment: Why are you trying to build a page's content like this?  I think your code problem could be highlighting a design/implementation problem.  Tell us what you're trying to accomplish and I think we can help even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you provided is throwing an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: posterurl is not defined
```

After adding `var posterurl = "";`, the code executed properly and performantly.

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/JvRy5/).

**Note:** This is a **horrible** way to build a page.

Comment: Thank you - I know its horrible, hence the second part of the question. If I have the same general structure for each wrapper, how can I best build multiple wrappers on the same page?

Comment: If you want to see what I am trying to accomplish visually go to www.jackdent.co.uk/vintage

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your expanded question (thanks for taking the time), my instinct says that you're better off performing this on the server-side.  This means that the document that you send comes pre-built with content, which has a major impact on an important visitor - Google.  Otherwise, as far as the google-bots are concerned, your pages are empty and possibly hiding content, which they are strongly opposed to.  A server-side built page also means that visitors with JavaScript disabled will get the same content.  Loading content dynamically is fine and can be very useful, but building so much of the page from scratch in JavaScript is going a little too far (in my opinion).

Comment: I agree completely - 2 problems: 1. I am not confident with PHP or likewise any other server side script...yet :) 2. I have it already working basically with jQuery, and I know implementation from an array  is not too unachievable...

Comment: PHP is totally worth learning.  Besides, if you don't have some server side technology, where are you going to get the content to put in your array?  If you're inputting it manually, you're 100% better off making static HTML than building a static page that builds itself with JavaScript.  That's a load of complexity and maintenance that gives no benefit.

Comment: I concede defeat... I just wanted an easy way for users to input data into the page so they don't have to trawl through HTML if they are inexperienced. How simple is wordpress integration for something like this?

Comment: Think of it as a win - you are going to build a better solution!  And trust me, working in HTML is better for basic users that JS is.  Wordpress is great for integrating and you can do lots of things with it beyond a basic WP site.  The developers built it in such a way that you can do a lot with it.  You'll also learn lots about PHP on your way - another win :)